# Spotipy: Localhost not connecting despite matching redirect_uris

Tags: python, localhost, spotipy

I'm building a simple application using the Spotipy API. It has been working for myself and now I'm trying to expand it so that users can log in with their spotify account. When I try to obtain the link for them to verify their credentials and open it in browser, the localhost refuses to connect.

I'm using the SpoityOAuth method, passing in my client_id and client_secret, along with a redirect_uri (http://localhost:8888/callback), and then I'm calling the get_authorize_url() method to get the link and using webbrowser.open to open that link in browser. My credentials and redirect uri are consistent with my developer settings and my program, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the code:
`# sp_oauth = SpotifyOAuth(client_id= cred.client_id, client_secret= cred.client_secret,redirect_uri= cred.redirect_url, scope='user-top-read')  url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url() webbrowser.open(url)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
from pprint import pprint

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=cred.client_id,client_secret=cred.client_secret,redirect_uri=cred.redirect_url,scope="user-top-read"))

data = sp.current_user_top_artists(limit=20, offset=0, time_range='medium_term')
pprint(data)
```